# How to get any suitable font in ImageSharp?

Tags: c#, fonts, imagesharp

I am very tired of providing fonts for my application. It would be a lot easier to have some ready-to-use fonts collection that I can use.

See this

```cs
//I need to add text to image, no matter what font is
var fo = SystemFonts.Find("Mono");
var font = new Font(fo, 10f, FontStyle.Regular);
x.DrawText("123", font,color,point);
```

I need to be sure that computer running this piece of code have font `Mono` installed. But it is not always the case, so I had to keep font file in my project folder and so on...
This is just annoying.

What I want to do

```cs
//this must be a font that included into library itself.
var font = FontCollection.Any;
x.DrawText("123", font,color,point);
```

With this I can be sure that I will be able to print text on image no matter what system is.

Comment: There is an discussion in github saying why this is not a case for library and shipping fonts with lib is not a good idea
https://github.com/SixLabors/Fonts/discussions/227